# How to begin neural network Programming

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I am a Computer Science Student and recently studied neural networks, but theory only. How can this be implemented in real time programming language. What should I search for or what content should I read so that I can do programs using neural network.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the neural network? Machine intelligence applications or mimicking biologically plausible human cognition?

Comment: Machine intelligence applications

Answer (score 5):

A google search for [neural network library](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=neural%20network%20library) will return many relevant pages, with neural network libraries written in several programming languages.

You could also look for [tutorials on programming perceptrons](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=programming%20a%20perceptron%20tutorial) which are among the most basic neural networks. This would teach you how to actually program the network from scratch, instead of using a pre-made library.

[This walkthrough](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14342/Designing-And-Implementing-A-Neural-Network-Librar) covers the development of a more complex neural network library if you are looking to jump right into building multilayer networks.

Answer (score 1):

Take [this](https://www.udacity.com/course/progress#!/c-ud675) course at Udacity. From my experience the course quality there is high and will save you a great deal of research time. You can also try https://www.coursera.org/course/neuralnets. Usually courses are coursera are of a great quality. The bottom line is take a MOOC first.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/index.html) is a free, entry-level e-book.

Answer (score 1):

There are many advanced tutorials which would suit someone with a computer science background, but if you are interested in the connection between neural networks and psychology/cognitive science then these two volumes are very accessible and give enough details to start coding your own networks:

Parallel Distributed Processing, Volume 1
Explorations in the Microstructure of Cognition: Foundations
By David E. Rumelhart, James L. McClelland and PDP Research Group (1986)
https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/parallel-distributed-processing

Another book with practical details and a good connection to psychology is

An Introduction to Neural Networks by Kevin Gurney (1997)
[no link, I don't have the reputation]

Both are severely out of date with respect to the cutting edge of modern neural networks, but the fundamentals don't go out of date so I figure they are a good place to start

Comment: The Gurney book gets my recommendation as well. It's a very approachable and well-written text.